# CannotLoadBeanClassException in first spring app

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm attempting my first data access example using Spring and have run into this CannotLoadBeanClassException in reference to a class noted in applicationContext.xml file. Here's my directory structure:

[image]

My applicationContext.xml file:

[image]

When the applicationContext.xml file is read it complains that it cannot find the file JDBCTest.  I don't get it. The application compiles fine and the class files are in the target folder. The path is correct in the xml file: com.example.jdbcdataaccess.JDBCTest

So why am I getting:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.example.djbcdataaccess.JDBCTest] for bean with name 'JDBCTest' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.djbcdataaccess.JDBCTest
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1385)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:641)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.example.jdbcdataaccess.JdbcdataaccessApplication.main(JdbcdataaccessApplication.java:12)
```

Comment: You have a typo: `com.example.djbcdataaccess.JDBCTest`, but your package is called `jbcdataaccess`, with no `d`.

Comment: It's actually `jdbcdataaccess`

Comment: Of course...it had to be something like that...couldn't see the forest for the trees.  Thanks.